# New page with window print

Tags: html, css

I have a table and two popup windows that I'm looking to print out when the action is called. The issue that i'm having is that page-break in css isn't working and no other solution that i have tried is work either. At the moment the two pop up windows display on top of the table data and i'm looking to have them either on new pages or one after the other.

HTML

```
<div class="printable">

<table class="table">
    <th>Option 1</th>
    <th>Option 2</th>
    <tr>
        <td><input class="span6 text-center" type="text" id="cost1"></td>
        <td><input class="span6 text-center" type="text" id="cost2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <div class="popup" data-popup="popup1">
        <p>Need to print this as well</p>
    </div>

    <div class="popup" data-popup="popup2">
        <p>Need to print this as well</p>
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="Print" class="btn btn-success" onclick="window.print();" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.popup {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

@media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
     .printable * {
        visibility: visible;
     }
     .popup {
         display: block;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According w3c(see the `fixed` part): https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position

> UAs must not paginate the content of fixed boxes.

So `position: fixed` can't paginate even if you set a `top: 100%` to second `.popup`.

And in your sample the second `.popup` is overlay the first one.

By changing `.popup`'s position to `absolute` and give the second one this style:

```
.popup:nth-of-type(2) {
  page-break-before: always;
  top: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fp2gkm17/

Comment: Thanks for the information. Wasn't aware of the fixed position issue.